# specifying classpath for standalone jython

Tags: mysql, jython

I am trying to run a python script via jython on a server that I won't be able to install anything.

I can run

```
java -jar jython.jar
```

and that works fine. I am unable to use mm.mysql-2.0.14 driver because it can't find the jar. I set the classpath to include it, as I did on a test system with a standard (that is, non-standalone) jython install. It still says it can't find the jar.

I have tried things like:

`export  CLASSPATH=/tmp/mm.mysql-2.0.14-bin.jar:/tmp/zxJDBC.jar; 
java -jar jython.jar`

and

```
java -cp /tmp/mm.mysql-2.0.14-bin.jar  -jar jython.jar
```

no dice.

still the error: zxJDBC.DatabaseError: driver [org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver] not found

Answer (score 4):

In my Windows environment I was able to run:

```
java -cp c:\jars\ojdbc6.jar;c:\jython2.5.2\jython.jar org.python.util.jython schema_ora.py
```

where `schema_ora.py` is a script I want to run which uses Oracle JDBC driver.

I also tried it on Linux with:

```
[mn@test-db mn]# export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/jars/ojdbc6.jar; /usr/local/jython2.5.2/bin/jython -J-Xmx4048m schema_ora.py jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.19.128:1521:testdb usr passwd
```

So it is possible to run script that way.

As for your problem maybe you do not have rights to see MySQL JDBC driver?
I assume you use Linux, so you can check if you can see that file:

```
file /tmp/mm.mysql-2.0.14-bin.jar
```

I tried it with Oracle driver on my Linux box:

```
[mn@test-db mn]# file /usr/local/jars/ojdbc6.jar
/usr/local/jars/ojdbc6.jar: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) ...

> -jar
>
> When you use this option, **the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.**

So it it not possible to add anything to the classpath when using -jar.  You'd either have to repackage the jython.jar to include the required classes, or preferably use [Michał Niklas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22595/micha%c5%82-niklas) solution of adding the jython.jar to the classpath (either using -cp or CLASSPATH) and running the org.python.util.jython class directly.