# JDBC driver not found error in monkeyrunner/jython

Tags: mysql, jdbc, centos, classpath, jython

I need to Insert something in the `DB`. im using `JDBC` as a `connector, jython the script`, `mysql` the DB and the script is running in `CentOS`.

my code looks something like this:

> from `com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage`
>
> from `com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC`
>
> ```
>   db=zxJDBC.connect("jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306/dbname","USER","PASSWORD","org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver")
> ```

`c=db.cursor() c.execute("INSERT INTO tablename values ('X','X','X')")`

before that, I downloaded and decompressed the file from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) (in the desktop)

I added the path to classpath by doing this

```
 export PATH=/home/XX/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22
```

and when I ran the script, it gave me this error

> `zxJDBC.DatabaseError.driver [org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver]` not found

what have I done wrong? is the name of the driver name correct? because I just copied it in one of the tutorials that I've seen. or probably did I install the driver correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: i hope you have assigned  the right jar to  the classpath ?make sure that the jar is readable with the permissions?

Comment: @Thanga how do I know which one is the correct jar? I found 1 jar in root folder of the extracted file. It is named mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar . And then I copied path of that file and tried to put it add it in the classpath by doing what is stated above. how do I know thatitreadeacle wth permission? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

this is how I managed to solve the error:

1. Download the JDBC driver [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
2. Extract the tar.gz file anywhere you want.
3. You will find mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar inside that folder. Copy that and paste to (in my case) /%android-sdk%/tools/lib
4. Add the new location of mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar to classpath
5. do the script like this

> from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice,
> MonkeyImage
>
> from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
>
> db=zxJDBC.connect("jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3306/dbname","USER","PASSWORD","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
>
> c=db.cursor()
>
> c.execute("INSERT INTO tablename values ('X','X','X')")
>
> db.commit()

Hope this helps to those who will need it in the future. :)

Comment: [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110460/how-to-improve-accept-rate-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: Hey, @srhsnl. It's okay to accept your own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you running jython?  If you're using the standalone install, i.e. java -jar jython.jar, then from the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) ...

> -jar
>
> When you use this option, **the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.**

... you can't add anything to the classpath.  Repackaging the required classes into the jython jar is one approach or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312444/1680088) has an alternative solution - basically add the jython.jar to the classpath too (either using -cp or CLASSPATH) and run the org.python.util.jython class directly.

Answer (score -1):

I got the sample problem in windows7,I slove this problem by this:

1. download the JDBC driver
2. add the mysql-connector-java-ver-bin.jar to envionment variables: 
   such as:
   CLASSPATH : C:\xxx-path\mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar

then I slove this problem

Comment: Despite the different path – which can obviously change between systems – this solution is very similar to the OP's one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12909198/1128918