# Mysql database connection with Jython

Tags: jython, mysql-python

Hello i'm trying to get a mysql database connection with jython.
I'm using Python 3.3.2 and Jython 2.5.3

My code looks like this:

```
import sys
from java.sql import *
sys.path.append("C:\\dev\\git\\LogAnalysis\\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar")
con = DriveManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/statistik", "root", "admin")
stmt = con.createStatement()
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM search")
```

and so on. (Only a code snippet)

Each time i get the exeption:

java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/statistik

Can someone give me a tip?

Comment: See here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907260/jdbc-driver-not-found-error-in-monkeyrunner-jython

Comment: Are you sure JDBC driver is in `c:\dev\git\...`? Also try to add code: `from java.lang import Class; Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

Answer (score 4):

See solution at: [Jython CLASSPATH, sys.path and JDBC drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015059/jython-classpath-sys-path-and-jdbc-drivers)

For me the easiest solution is to provide batch/shell script which sets CLASSPATH. This looks like:

```
SET CLASSPATH=C:\dev\git\LogAnalysis\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar;%CLASSPATH%
CALL jython your_program.py %1 ...
```

Then you can remove line with:

```
sys.path.append(...)
```